# How to get the HTML TABLE Particular row Values using java script?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I created a table and put it data retrieving from fire base.

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td  class="th">Title</td>
        <td  class="th">First Name</td>
        <td  class="th">Last Name</td>
        <td  class="th">Hospital</td>
        <td  class="th">Spciality</td>
        <td  class="th">Doctor Fee</td>
        <td  class="th">Mobile Number</td>
        <td  class="th">Address</td> 
        <td  class="th">Actions</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="doctorlist">

<script>
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("User/doctor");

 rootRef.on("child_added",snap =>{
  var fname=snap.child("Firstname").val();
  var lname=snap.child("Lastname").val();
  var id=snap.child("DoctorID").val();
  var dob=snap.child("DOB").val();
  var address=snap.child("Doctor_Address").val();
  var email=snap.child("E-mail").val();
  var mobile=snap.child("Mobile_no").val();
  var hometp=snap.child("Home_no").val();
  var sex=snap.child("Sex").val();
  var hospital=snap.child("Hospital").val();
  var slmcno=snap.child("SLMC_Number").val();
  var speciality=snap.child("Spciality").val();
  var emargancyperson=snap.child("Emargency_person").val();
  var emargancyrelationship=snap.child("Emargency_reletionship").val();
  var emargancymobile=snap.child("Emargency_TP").val();
  var fee=snap.child("Doctor_fee").val();
  var nic=snap.child("NICNo").val();
  var title=snap.child("Title").val();

  //var lname=snap.child("DocotID").val();

  $("#doctorlist").append("<tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+fname+"</td><td>"+lname+"</td><td>"+hospital+"</td><td>"+speciality+"</td><td>"+"Rs."+fee+".00"+"</td><td>"+mobile+"</td><td>"+address+"</td><td><button>Remove</button></td></tr>");

 });

</script>
```

This is working perfectly.But I want to get cell data to variables, when i click on specific row.

I used this script

```
<script>
    var table = document.getElementById('doctorlist');

    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        table.rows[i].onclick = function() {
            //rIndex = this.rowIndex;

            alert(this.cells[0].innerHTML + this.cells[1].innerHTML + this.cells[2].innerHTML...........);
        };
    }
</script>
```

It is ok to hard-cored tale but is doesn't work for this. how can I solve this?